# etterfilter pcre_regex : difficulties with binary strings

Tags: regex, pcre, packet-sniffers, mitmproxy, network-analysis

that works great

```
replace("\x02\x03\x04", "\x05\x06\x07")
```

but that do not work

```
pcre_regex(DATA.data, "\x02\x03\x04", "\x05\x06\x07")
```

cause the \x is not interpreted in the replace string

i have tried to do

```
if ( search(DATA.data, "\x02\x03\x04") )
{
  log(DATA.data, "./D")
  exec("/bin/sed 's/\x02\x03\x04/\x05\x06\x07/g' ./D > ./E")
  drop()
  inject("./E")
}
```

but the exec seems to launch command in background
so inject() happen before ./E is wrote

=> which way are we intended to use pcre_regex with binary strings ?

=> is there another way to use etterfilter ?

=> is there another tool that do the job (binary replacement WITH regex) ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with this online tool?
https://www.debuggex.com/

this will help you in finding out if the bug is in ettercap or in pcre or in your regex :)

Answer (score 0):

answer is here 
https://github.com/Ettercap/ettercap/issues/488

answer is here 
https://github.com/Ettercap/ettercap/issues/488